# Object.values vs Array.from, what's the difference?

Tags: javascript

I recently faced issues where I couldn't use .map on iterable objects and had to convert them to arrays with either Object.values or Array.from

I seem to get same result in both cases, so I'm wondering what the difference is. In which case do you use one over the other?

Comment: The `Array.from()` static method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.
The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provide

Answer (score 4):

It's not true in the general case that you'll get the same result from [`Array.from(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`Object.values(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) when `x` is an iterable object. In fact, it's fairly rare (just arrays and array-likes¹ that hide their `length` property by making it non-enumerable or inheriting it and don't have any other own, enumerable properties). `Array.from` will loop through the iterable object using iteration; `Object.values` will loop through the object looking for own, enumerable properties. For an array that doesn't have any non-array properties, that ends up being the same thing, but it's not true in the general case.

In the general case, `Array.from` and `Object.values` do very different things and have different results:

- `Array.from` creates an array from any iterable **or** array-like object (an object with a `length` and index properties like 0 and 1).
- `Object.values` creates an array of the values of an object's own enumerable properties. The object doesn't have to be iterable (`Object.values` doesn't even look to see if it is.)
- `Array.from` accepts a second argument, a function that can be used to map the values from the iterable/array-like into new values for the array.

Here's an example where `Object.values` gets `[]` (because the `Set` has no own enumerable properties) but `Array.from` gets `[1, 2, 3]` (because the `Set`'s iterator provides those three values):

```js
const x = new Set([1, 2, 3]);

// Shows an empty array
console.dir(Object.values(x));
// Shows [1, 2, 3]
console.dir(Array.from(x));
```

Conversely, here's one where `Object.values` returns `[1, 2, 3]` because the object has those as own enumerable properties, but `Array.from` returns `[]` because the object is neither iterable nor array-like:

```js
const x = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

// Shows [1, 2, 3];
console.dir(Object.values(x));
// Shows []
console.dir(Array.from(x));
```

---

¹ An *array-like object* is an object with:

- A `length` property
- Properties named with strings that are numbers in the normal decimal form for the values `0` through `length - 1` (but there can be gaps).

For instance, this is an array-like object:

```
const obj = {0: "zero", 1: "one", length: 2};
```

(I've used number literals for the property names, but they'll be converted to string.)

Note that that object will give you different results for `Array.from` and `Object.values` because `length` is an own, inherited property.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to clarify ! makes a lot more sense now  :)

Answer (score 0):

`Array.from` creates a new array, usually from another array, but can also be used on `Set`. It also has a second arguments, that allows to map each element to another value.

`Object.values` on the other hand creates a new `array` with the values from the supplied object.

I'm not exactly sure why you say they do the same thing, as they don't. Except maybe the fac that you end up with an array as the results. Take this example for instance:

```
Object.values({a: 2, b:3}) // will return [2, 3]

on the other hand

Array.from({a: 2, b:3}) // will return [], as an object is not an array-like object
```

Comment: Array.from accepts *'An array-like or iterable object'*, worth linking to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#parameters)

Comment: They definitely don't do the same thing, but can return same result in some cases, which I think OP had encountered, eg:

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
Array.from(arr) // [1,2,3]
Object.values(arr) // [1,2,3]
```